# What size conductors would I need for a 10 ft. extension cord for a plasma cutter?

Tags: wiring

I would like to have a 10ft extention cord for my 220v plasma cutter. I just put a 3 prong (crow foot) connector on it to match the plug for my Lincoln arc welder and I would like to be able to move it around some. Would 10/3 wire be enough?

Comment: What is the amp draw?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to extensions used for welding and high current draw, I would not factor the cord size based on amp draw alone. Essentially the biggest problem you will face is heat generated within the cord. This is increased if you keep your cord rolled up whilst using it (the electromagnetic effect leading to an induction field). What I am saying is that when I use the welder for long periods of time, my cable gets hot, and as a result the rubber gets soft, any time I bump or kink the cord there is an increased chance of a breakage.